# Chrome: this extension loaded itself too frequently

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I’m building a custom Chrome extension. Sporadically my extension shows this message.

***This extension loaded itself too frequently***

What does this mean? Maybe I’m exceeding some threshold which disables the extension?

Answer (score 9):

You've called [`chrome.runtime.reload`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#method-reload) too often.

Chrome considers a reload a "fast reload" when you call `chrome.runtime.reload` within ten seconds after loading the extension. When your extension triggers more than five "fast reloads", then the following warning will be shown in the UI:

> This extension reloaded itself too frequently.

Comment: Hi Rob, I know this is a old discussion, but where did you gathered this information? I've searched a lot and didn't found anything.
In my tests, it appears Chrome no more wait for this ten seconds after load the extension. Now anytime, in the 6th call, it will block the extension no matter what. :(
I've even opened a new discussion for that, you can see it here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44522301/chrome-runtime-reload-blocking-the-extension?noredirect=1#comment76036549_44522301

Comment: @RubensPinheiro It's not documented, I read it in the source code, see the callers of https://cs.chromium.org/EXTENSION_WARNING_RELOAD_TOO_FREQUENT. It was introduced by https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/e9d7496ee1703754c5d56027aa2758a09c473c0a

Comment: Thanks for the info Rob! I'll try to ask the dev team if they can disable this or set a better limit for unpacked extensions.  

I've tested and even with 1 minute after loading the extension, and with 5 seconds between each "chrome.runtime.reload" call, the extension is always blocked on the 6th call. This turns the hot-reloading plugin that I'm developing impracticable.

Comment: [chrome.developerPrivate.reload](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/developerPrivate#method-reload) might be an option without this issue.

Comment: chrome.developerPrivate.* is restricted to whitelisted apps and extensions (designed to only be used by components of Chrome itself).