# chrome.runtime.reload blocking the extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

So, I'm developing a plugin for webpack for hot-reloading the chrome extensions.
The biggest problem is, if I call a certain number of times the "chrome.runtime.reload()" this will make Chrome block the extension:

```
This extension reloaded itself too frequently.
```

On a [old discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29086691/chrome-this-extension-loaded-itself-too-frequently) they said that if you call the reload more than 5 times in a 10 seconds time frame, your extension will be blocked.
The thing is, I've throttled the reloading a lot (like max 1 call each 5 seconds) and this still happening. I've searched a lot on the docs. but didn't found anything related to this, so I'm kind of in the dark.

So there's really a threshold for this or you only can call the runtime reload a fixed number of times before it blocks the extension?

UPDATE:
To deal with this problem, I've requested a new feature for the Chromium team, [Let disable the "Fast Reload" blocking for unpacked extensions](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=733209#c1). If anyone have the same problems, please give a star on this feature request :)

Comment: I think you misinterpreted the old discussion. It's actually saying that if you reload within ten seconds of the extension starting that counts against you, instead of five times within ten seconds. So it seems like if you make sure to wait more than ten seconds to start then you should be ok.

Comment: Well, even after ten seconds, the results are the same :(
I've waited like a minute after starting call the runtime reload, and in the sixth call, it blocked. So, it appears to be a fixed "magic" number not described in any docs.

Comment: That's lousy. I know that Rob W who answered the question on the old discussion is the best source on questions like this, so maybe send him a message directly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the threshold has been reached (i.e. reloaded 5 times in quick succession), you have to wait at least 10 seconds before the counter resets and the extension can safely be reloaded.

[Source](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/bfe6ca7a755f69fe8a8bcc6986f1edd5cd0860aa/chrome/browser/extensions/api/runtime/chrome_runtime_api_delegate.cc#173) (trimmed code to emphasize the relevant logic):

```cpp
  std::pair<base::TimeTicks, int>& reload_info =
      last_reload_time_[extension_id];
  base::TimeTicks now = base::TimeTicks::Now();
  if (reload_info.first.is_null() ||
      (now - reload_info.first).InMilliseconds() > kFastReloadTime) {
    reload_info.second = 0;
  } else {
    reload_info.second++;
  }

  // ....

  reload_info.first = now;
  ExtensionService* service =
      ExtensionSystem::Get(browser_context_)->extension_service();
  if (reload_info.second >= kFastReloadCount) {
    // ....
    base::ThreadTaskRunnerHandle::Get()->PostTask(
        FROM_HERE, base::BindOnce(&ExtensionService::TerminateExtension,
                                  service->AsWeakPtr(), extension_id));
    extensions::WarningSet warnings;
    warnings.insert(
        extensions::Warning::CreateReloadTooFrequentWarning(
            extension_id));
```

With `kFastReloadTime` and `kFastReloadCount` defined [here](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/dd45b8a2d44b4077247e22afdc092889e20795b5/chrome/browser/extensions/api/runtime/chrome_runtime_api_delegate.cc#56):

```cpp
// If an extension reloads itself within this many miliseconds of reloading
// itself, the reload is considered suspiciously fast.
const int kFastReloadTime = 10000;
// After this many suspiciously fast consecutive reloads, an extension will get
// disabled.
const int kFastReloadCount = 5;
```